# Trying to rank by group on a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, rank

I have this query in which I am trying to group by position and rank by Final Value.

```
SELECT qryProspects.[Prospect Name]
       , qryProspects.Position
       , qryProspects.Height
       , qryProspects.Weight
       , qryProspects.College
       , qryProspects.RoundID
       , Round([AvgOfAggregate],2) AS [True Value]
       , Round([AvgOfAggregate]*[Multiplier]*[NeedMultiplier],2) AS [Final Value]
       , qryProspects.ProspectID    
  FROM qryProspects
       INNER JOIN qryCalculations ON qryProspects.ProspectID = qryCalculations.ProspectID;
```

So the results would rank all the QB's from 1 being highest, then all the RBs the same, then all of the WR's, etc....

Any help is with much appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table. Try this

```
SELECT [Prospect Name]
       , Position
       , Height
       , Weight
       , College
       , RoundID
       , [True Value]
       , [Final Value]
       , ProspectID
  FROM (SELECT qryProspects.[Prospect Name]
               , qryProspects.Position
               , qryProspects.Height
               , qryProspects.Weight
               , qryProspects.College
               , qryProspects.RoundID
               , Round([AvgOfAggregate],2) AS [True Value]
               , Round([AvgOfAggregate]*[Multiplier]*[NeedMultiplier],2) AS [Final Value]
               , qryProspects.ProspectID    
          FROM qryProspects
               INNER JOIN qryCalculations ON qryProspects.ProspectID = qryCalculations.ProspectID)
    AS QB_ORDER
 GROUP BY Position
 ORDER BY [Final Value]
```

Comment: returns an error- cannot group on fields selected with "*"